# react native:how to understand device is rooted?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, rooted-device

I want to know if the device has been rooted, or not? I looked at react native library as well as the expo and did not find anything.

Also I want to have a list of installed apps on the phone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this library to identify if a phone is rooted or mocking locations.

https://github.com/GantMan/jail-monkey

```
import JailMonkey from 'jail-monkey'

// is this device JailBroken on iOS/Android?
JailMonkey.isJailBroken()

// Can this device mock location - no need to root!
JailMonkey.canMockLocation()

// Check if device violates any of the above
JailMonkey.trustFall()

// (ANDROID ONLY) Check if application is running on external storage
JailMonkey.isOnExternalStorage()
```

Comment: it gives an error "can not read isJailBroken of undefined." for iOS.

Comment: @DharmendraVaishnav after `npm install`, you'll have to `react-native link`, and then cd into the ios project and `pod install` -- that's what worked for me